# How to override the current system date within junits

Tags: java, swing, junit

I want to get curent system date overriden into my Junits.Please help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to override/control the way the JVM gets the system date?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2548922/how-to-override-control-the-way-the-jvm-gets-the-system-date)

Comment: Can you specify a bit more how do you get your date in order to give you better answers?

Comment: We are using a swing application and we have market calendar manager with commands and events in it . We are using calendar date to get our date.

Answer (score 2):

One technique I use is to NOT call the usual Date/Calendar factory methods/constructors, nor System.getCurrentTimeMillis.  Instead I inject a date/time "factory," namely an interface with methods for whatever I need in the way of getting the system time.

Then during test I inject an instance which I control directly (hard-coding the time, or even storing it in a file, depending on what I'm testing).   Otherwise I inject an implementation which makes the appropriate real calls to the system.

It's not as much work as it sounds, and makes testing time/date-sensitive code fairly straightforward.

Answer (score 1):

Not really an answer, but maybe your code should be changed so rather than you having to hack up the date object you just pass in the date as an argument, that way you can just pass in whatever you want to unit test that method/code.

Another option would be to make a date interface of some kind then mock that out to return whatever you want, mockito may be able to let you make a dummy date object if its not final and you could then get that to return whatever you want.

Answer (score 1):

You coud use [Powermock](http://code.google.com/p/powermock/) which allows mocking of static and final methods.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure of how are you getting your system date, but just an idea: Have you tried to use Mocks (EasyMock/Mockito)?

Comment: No I didnt try that , Can you please tell how to use Mocks

Answer (score 0):

If you use [Joda time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/), then you can [override the time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/userguide.html#Change_the_Current_Time) used when constructing `DateTime` and other classes. In effect, you are using Joda as your factory for date and time objects.

Using Joda is much preferred to using the poorly-designed JDK `Calendar` class.